# How to manually throw HTTP 404 Not Found exception in spray/akka?

Tags: scala, akka, slick, spray, slick-3.0

In my repository function, I'm reading a User, then updating that user:

```
def update(u: User): Future[Int] = {
    this.read(u.id).flatMap {
      case Some(existingUser) =>
        db.run(
          userTable
            .filter(_.id === user.id)
            .update(user.copy(createdDate = existingUser.createdDate)))
      //case None => throw new NotFoundException(); // does this exception exist in spray/akka?
    }
}
```

I'd like to throw some sort of exception here when the user is not found, so that spray/akka will know that exception means to return HTTP 404 Not Found.

Does spray/akka contain some sort of NotFoundException that I can manually throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw any exception and then configure an [exception handler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/routing-dsl/exception-handling.html#exception-handling) to convert the exception to 404 response.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be an exception, or could you use this:

```
      case None => HttpResponse(StatusCodes.NotFound)
```